# Initial store is loaded when store is deleted from local storage redux-persist

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, next.js, redux-persist

I am using Next.js(SSr) with redux. I have successfully implemented react-persist with the nextjs.

the user state is updated after login and value is update in the redux store and simultaneously in the localStorage's store  but whenever I delete the localStorage item which contains the store and refresh the page,the localStorage is filled by the first version of the store i.e the initial store.
I though there might be problem in re hydration but i think PersistGate is handling it efficiently.
Can someone point out what went wrong in implementation ? 
thanks in advance :)

**_app.js**

```
import withRedux from 'next-redux-wrapper'
import { withRouter } from 'next/router'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import App from 'next/app'
import Layout from 'components/Layout'
import createStore from 'store/createStore'


import { persistStore } from 'redux-persist'
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react'

class MyApp extends App {
 static async getInitialProps ({ Component, ctx }) {
   return {
     pageProps: Component.getInitialProps
     ? await Component.getInitialProps(ctx)
     : {}
   }
 }

constructor(props) {
 super(props)
 this.persistor = persistStore(props.store)
}

render () {
 const { Component, pageProps, store, router } = this.props
 return (
  <>
   <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate
        loading={<Component {...pageProps} />}
        persistor={this.persistor}
      >
          <Layout>
            <Component router={router} {...pageProps} />
          </Layout>
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  </>
  )
 }
}

export default withRedux(createStore, {debug: true})(
 withRouter(MyApp)
)
```

**createStore.js**

```
import Immutable from 'immutable'
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk'
import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger'
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension'
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'

import { persistReducer } from 'redux-persist'
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage'

import config from 'config'
import rootReducer from '../reducers'

const persistConfig = {
 key: 'primary',
 storage,
 whitelist: ['user'],
}

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer)

function createMiddlewares ({ isServer }) {
 const middlewares = [
  thunkMiddleware
 ]

if (config.env === 'development' && typeof window !== 'undefined') {
 middlewares.push(createLogger({
   level: 'info',
   collapsed: true,
   stateTransformer: (state) => {
     const newState = {}

     for (const i of Object.keys(state)) {
       if (Immutable.Iterable.isIterable(state[i])) {
         newState[i] = state[i].toJS()
       } else {
         newState[i] = state[i]
       }
     }

     return newState
   }
 }))
 }

return middlewares
}

function immutableChildren (obj) {
 const state = {}
 Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
  state[key] = Immutable.fromJS(obj[key])
 })
 return state
}

export default (initialState = {}, context) => {
 const { isServer } = context
 const middlewares = createMiddlewares({ isServer })
 const state = immutableChildren(initialState)

 return createStore(
    persistedReducer,
    state,
    composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middlewares))
   )
 }
```

**Img: initial store loaded instead of updated store after localStorage item is removed and page is refreshed**

[image: Updated store data is not been reloaded]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the redux-persist you no need to bind the PersistGate with provider...you can remove it and try again hope it will solve your issue...This is because you are already wrapping the component with withRedux hook.

```
return (
      <PersistGate
        loading={<Component {...pageProps} />}
        persistor={this.persistor}
      >
          <Layout>
            <Component router={router} {...pageProps} />
          </Layout>
      </PersistGate>
  )
```

This will be enough